# UIViewController didn't present immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

And view controller presents after 5-6 seconds after i click the button first time only. After first time presenting latter works ok.

What seems to be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Posting some code will help us answer your question

Comment: The loading of the viewcontroller seems to be taking some time. Check the nib file, the `viewDidLoad` and `awakeFromNib` methods.

Comment: Make sure you are calling `-presentViewController:animated:completion:` from the main thread. Other than that, use Time Profiler in Product > Profile.

Comment: Post method code from where you call presentViewController...

Comment: Not only the `awakeFromNib` issue as said by @rckoenes, but also check for any heavy load processes in `viewDidLoad` of `presentingViewController` as those processes will run on main thread.

Comment: here is my code: 
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ConfigurationViewController *viewController = [ConfigurationViewController new];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is some url download process has been started in `ViewController` `viewDidLoad` method, which is eventually blocking till the download has been completed. Though it works second time fine, because of cache, and it downloads faster than first time.

I suggest you to use `dispatch block` like below

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Download Code
        [self download];
});
```

or, alternatively you can create a function say

```
-(void)download{

}
```

and call it using

```
[self performSelector:@selector(download) withObject:nil afterDelay:.1];
```

all in **`viewDidLoad`**.

All will work without any problem.

And too you can choose to add `UIActivityIndicator` to show user an activity for download.

Hope it helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Not only the `awakeFromNib` issue said by @rckoenes, but also check for any heavy load processes in `viewDidLoad` of `presentingViewController` as those processes will run on main thread. The heavy load processes may be 
 1. Downloading an image and fixing it to image,
 2. Drawing any high clarity image, 
 3. Downloading the data from internet (Ex: `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]`)etc.

This can be avoided by using threads.

If this is not the case, please let me know what is the process you wanted to run in `viewDidLoad` of `presentingViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is happening on the main thread?
You can confirm as follows:

```
if(! [NSThread isMainThread] )
{
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(),
    ^{
        // Continue here
    } );
}
```